# queryselector error not a valid selector javascript

Tags: javascript

```
let selector = document.querySelector(`[data-id=${element.id}}]`);
```

produces an error

```
Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[data-id=484}]' is not a valid selector.
```

any idea how can I fix this ?

Comment: Typo - you have one opening brace but two closing ones -(`[data-id=${element.id}}]`);

Comment: still im getting DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[data-id=484]' is not a valid selector.

Comment: try using the back-ticks only in the interpolated content and as Casper suggests -  use quotes around the whole thing("[data-id=\`${element.id}\`]");

Comment: wrap you element with ", let selector = document.querySelector("[data-id=\""+element.id+"\""), let selector = document.querySelector(`[data-id="${element.id}"]`);

Comment: i fix it by using [data-id="${element.id}"]. I Just add a qoutes inside it

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have an extra closing curly bracket.  Try:

```
let selector = document.querySelector(`[data-id=${element.id}]`);
```

**EDIT**

Try also putting quotes around the attribute value:

```
let selector = document.querySelector(`[data-id="${element.id}"]`);
```

Comment: still im getting